# Math.pow alternative "**" ES7 polyfill for IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, modernizr, polyfills, ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to evaluate an expression which contains power, in string as `**`. i.e. `eval("(22**3)/12*6+3/2")`.The problem is Internet Explorer 11 does not recognizes this and throws syntax error. Which poly-fill I should use to overcome this? Right now I'm using `Modernizr 2.6.2`.

example equation would be,

```
((1*2)*((3*(4*5)*(1+3)**(4*5))/((1+3)**(4*5)-1)-1)/6)/7
((1*2)*((3*(4*5)*(1+3)**(4*5))/((1+3)**(4*5)-1)-1)/6)/7*58+2*5
(4*5+4-5.5*5.21+14*36**2+69/0.258+2)/(12+65)
```

If it is not possible to do this, what are the possible alternatives?

Comment: It sounds like you need to write your own parser. Or find one that suits your needs.

Comment: A polyfill can't help you here because the code is parsed as a syntax error by old browsers. You must transform the code before it's read by the browser as code (preferably server-side using something like Babel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot polyfill operators - only library members (prototypes, constructors, properties).

As your operation is confined to an `eval` call, you could attempt to write your own expression parser, but that would be a lot of work.

(As an aside, you shouldn't be using `eval` anyway, for very good reasons that I won't get into in this posting).

Another (hack-ish) option is to use a regular expression to identify trivial cases of `x**y` and convert them to `Math.pow`:

```
function detectAndFixTrivialPow( expressionString ) {

    var pattern = /(\w+)\*\*(\w+)/i;

    var fixed = expressionString.replace( pattern, 'Math.pow($1,$2)' );
    return fixed;
}

eval( detectAndFixTrivialPow( "foo**bar" ) );
```

Comment: Actually, equation is too long. Each equation I'm parsing, contains almost 10-15 variables and 5-10 operators.

Comment: @Prajwal Please post more examples of the expressions you're evaluating then. And note that they are not "equations" because there's no equality being defined or satisfied, they're *expressions*.

Comment: Edited my question by adding more examples.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression to replace the occurrences of `**` with `Math.pow()` invocations:

```js
let expression = "(22**3)/12*6+3/2"
let processed = expression.replace(/(\w+)\*\*(\w+)/g, 'Math.pow($1,$2)');

console.log(processed);
console.log(eval(processed));
```

Things might get complicated if you start using nested or chained power expressions though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do some preprocessing of the input. Here is how i would approach this:

1. Find "**" in string.
2. Check what is on the left and right.
3. Extract "full expressions" from left and right - if there is just a number - take it as is, and if there is a bracket - find the matching one and take whatever is inside as an expression.
4. Replace the 2 expressions with Math.pow(left, right)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Babel online](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=ie%2011) to convert javascript for IE 11.